Tutor Lms showing editor of the course as an author along with the primary author
Our course shows two names for ‘Course by’, even though only one author is assigned. How do I change this to show just one?
I want to hide instructors other than the primary one, by overriding and customizing this instructors.php template.
As i'm not good with codes so can't figure out what to modify.
CODE:
do_action( 'tutor_course/single/enrolled/before/instructors' );

$instructors = tutor_utils()->get_instructors_by_course();
if ( $instructors && count( $instructors ) ) : ?>
<div class="tutor-course-details-instructors">
<h3 class="tutor-fs-6 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-mb-16">
<?php esc_html_e( 'A course by', 'tutor' ); ?>
</h3>
<?php foreach ( $instructors as $key => $instructor ) : ?>
    <div class="tutor-d-flex tutor-align-center<?php echo ( count( $instructors ) - 1 ) != $key ? ' tutor-mb-24' : ''; ?>">
        <div class="tutor-d-flex tutor-mr-16">
            <?php
            echo wp_kses(
                tutor_utils()->get_tutor_avatar( $instructor, 'md' ),
                tutor_utils()->allowed_avatar_tags()
            );
            ?>
        </div>
            <div>
            <a class="tutor-fs-6 tutor-fw-bold tutor-color-black" href="<?php echo esc_url( tutor_utils()->profile_url( $instructor->ID, true ) ); ?>">
                <?php echo esc_html( $instructor->display_name ); ?>
            </a>

            <?php if ( ! empty( $instructor->tutor_profile_job_title ) ) : ?>
                <div class="tutor-instructor-designation tutor-fs-7 tutor-color-muted">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $instructor->tutor_profile_job_title ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php
endif;

do_action( 'tutor_course/single/enrolled/after/instructors' );


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
